# Creating a certificate for apache without hostname

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl-certificate

I created a .crt certificate for Apache, however I could only import it to my java cacerts with the hostname I generated it with. This is for testing only and is self signed. I have both a hostname (local internal to network) and a public IP.

My question is, how can I generate a .crt file that would serve both my local host-name and my public IP (no public domain name)? Can it be ignorant of the domain?

(It's just for SSL test purposes) I need to access both from public IP and local internal host-name... (another IP).

I saw this [How to easily create a SSL certificate and configure it in Apache2 in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/73979/how-to-easily-create-a-ssl-certificate-and-configure-it-in-apache2-in-mac-os-x)

But this question and answer did not help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSL certificate will provides security based on domain name.  See the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854805/ip-based-ssl-certificate).